# Android Runtime Errorr

Tags: android

I am beginner android developer:)I dowland android sdk completely from 2.0 version to 4.2.I created a new project and added some buttons,checkboxs then I tried to run my first project and got a error like that:

```
[2012-12-25 00:09:13 - aaa]
[2012-12-25 00:09:13 - aaa] Android Launch!
[2012-12-25 00:09:13 - aaa] adb is running normally.

[2012-12-25 00:09:13 - aaa] Performing com.example.xxx.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-12-25 00:09:13 - aaa] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus_by_Google'
[2012-12-25 00:09:13 - aaa] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus_by_Google'
[2012-12-25 00:09:14 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist! 
[2012-12-25 00:09:14 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2012-12-25 00:09:14 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8 
[2012-12-25 00:09:14 - Emulator]
[2012-12-25 00:09:14 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2012-12-25 00:09:14 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Try with a different emulator.. That sometimes happen for specific emulator density settings or similar.

Comment: ty so much /now emulator working :)

Answer (score 0):

That sometimes happen for specific emulator density settings. Try with a different emulator, tweak its settings until you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error...

**Solution**

change **hw.ramSize** to 1024MB in *config.ini* file under

```
$User>.android>avd>name_of_avd> config.ini
```

It works fine